# How does the Authentication framework work for Multiple user for external plugin

Tags: oauth-2.0, banno-digital-toolkit

I'm using the https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/quickstarts/buildyourfirstplugin/ to test the authorization flow.

This example only talks about one user. what if I have mutilple users, how does the flow work for them. I don't see any idenfiers to differeciate between mutiple user in the auth flow

Please can you explain how the auth api will work more users enabled for external plugin.

Only able to test for one user. But how is the auth for different users attached to same clientid & client secret.

Answer (score 0):

### 1)

The [Getting Started](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/getting-started/) page for the Authentication Framework has a 1-minute video which is useful for context:

[image: Getting Started page for Authentication Framework]

The *Identity Token* will always have the `sub` (or 'unique subject identifier') *claim*. That identifier uniquely identifies a user within Banno for a given financial institution. It's also useful as the value for the `{userId}` parameter in any API path definitions.

The [Simple Plugin Example](https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example) code only requests a handful of *claims* for the Identity Token, but you can extend the example with more from the list here: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/

- You'll want to make sure to use the *Publicly Available Claims*.

### 2)

By the way, API credentials aren't tied to specific *users* but rather they are tied to specific *External Applications*. This means that the External Application can be accessed by multiple users (each of which is identified in the Identity Token as described above).